# becomeFirstResponder() is not bringing up the keyboard - Swift 5 - iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, ios14

I am really fresh in Swift coding. Hoping someone knows what is going wrong here.
In the code below, I am trying to bring up the keyboard when its loaded - Seems to be working on iPhone SE Simulator, however its not working in iPhone 11 Simulator. Please let me know if more details are needed.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var labelPasteboard: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        
    }

    @IBAction func trashPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        textField.text = ""
    }
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        labelPasteboard.text = "Hello \(textField.text!)"
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is your "hardware keyboard" connected in the iPhone 11 simulator?

Comment: Try hitting Command  K.

Comment: Trying adding it in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad.

Comment: Hi @jnpdx , no my H/W keyboard is not connected

Comment: @matt, no, doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Chris, still doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Vixter When the IBActions are called, do they function as expected?

Comment: @Vixter Also you need to ensure that in the simulator menu under I/O > Keyboard, make sure that Connect Hardware Keyboard is unticked. Sometimes it will automatically default to using your machine keyboard instead of using the software keyboard.

Comment: @Chris, that's gold ! Works :D . Like you said, the H/W Keyboard was attached and that's why it wasn't bringing up the software keyboard. At first, I couldn't find the keyboard (extreme novice :p ), then once I made the simulator full screen, found the I/O > Keyboard and as soon as I unchecked the "Use the Same Keyboard Language as macOS", the soft keyboard started popping up. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Chris Are you able to post the above as answer so I can upvote it =) ? Not sure if I can still do that as I am new in Stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Vixter Glad it worked for you. When learning, there are a lot of things that might catch you out including Xcode! Remember, we all had to start somewhere, I wish you well on your journey. I've added the answer below ;-)

Answer (score 0):

in your viewDidLoad the controller does don't know about your textField

try add

```
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for answering but it´s still not working. I tried both viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear

Comment: if it works on live Iphone SE, but doesn't work on simulator - may you close keyboard. Try press cmd+shift+k a few times for open keyboard

Comment: Hi Vladimir, yes, it works now :) Thanks for your response. I followed a suggestion above where @Chris suggested that in the simulator menu under I/O > Keyboard, to make sure that Connect Hardware Keyboard is unticked. Once I did that, it works =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that in the simulator menu under I/O > Keyboard, make sure that Connect Hardware Keyboard is unticked. Sometimes it will automatically default to using your machine keyboard instead of using the software keyboard.